# Python Script - module, main_function and package_runner contain error

Tags: python

I have a script that previously worked on an old server. This was kind of thrown at me, so forgive me with my lack of python knowledge. I studied plenty of other languages and have been troubleshooting this for days!

I have updated the paths appropriately but always get the following errors when running on a new error: 
[Powershell errors with line numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3biTm.png)

The line numbers given in the image are 241, 117, and 140. The code is as followed

```
def main_function(todayDate):
zipFileName = ''

print todayDate
for root, dirname, files in os.walk(workingDir, topdown=True):
    del dirname[:]
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('datawarehousefeed_' + currentDwfVersion) or file.startswith('datawarehousefeed_' + currentDwfVersionBackfill):
            if file.endswith('11692.zip'):
                if (file.__contains__('BACKFILL_') and file.split('_')[4] == todayDate) or (file.__contains__(todayDate) and 'BACKFILL_' not in file):
                    zipFileName = workingDir + '\\' + file
                    print zipFileName

                    if not os.path.exists(archiveDir):
                        os.mkdir(archiveDir)

                    if os.path.exists(processingDir):
                        shutil.rmtree(processingDir)
                    os.mkdir(processingDir)

                    if os.path.exists(finalDir):
                        shutil.rmtree(finalDir)
                    os.mkdir(finalDir)

                    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipFileName, 'r') as zf:
                        zf.extractall(processingDir)

                    for root, dirname, files in os.walk(processingDir):
                        for file in files:
                            if not (file.startswith('qmresult')):
                                 if not (file.startswith('rolepermission')):
                                      if file:
                                           if file:
                                              tableName = file[:file.find('_')]
                                              with open((processingDir + '\\' + file), 'rb') as read:
                                                  reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in read))
                                                  #reader = csv.reader(read)
                                                  with open((finalDir + '\\' + tableName + '.csv'), 'wb') as write:
                                                      writer = csv.writer(write, delimiter=',', quotechar="\"", lineterminator='\n')
                                                      for row in reader:
                                                          rowFixed = []
                                                          for column in row:
                                                              fixedColumn = string.replace(column, "\"", "\'\'")
                                                              fixedColumn2 = string.replace(fixedColumn, '\n', ' ')
                                                              rowFixed.append(fixedColumn2)
                                                          writer.writerow(rowFixed)
                                                      read.close
                                                      write.close
                    package_runner(zipFileName)
def package_runner(zipFileName):
try:
    retcode = subprocess.call(r'dtexec /f "FILE PATH HERE"', shell=True)
    if retcode > 0:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
        sendEmail("ssis failure", (zipFileName + " " + "DWF_1_A_ClaimAudit.dtsx" + " " + str(retcode)))
        print (10/0)
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode
except OSError as e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
    sendEmail("ssis failure", (zipFileName + " " + "DWF_1_A_ClaimAudit.dtsx" + " " +  e))
    sys.exit("error, exiting")

for single_date in daterange(startDate, endDate):
print single_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
todayDate = single_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
main_function(todayDate)
```

Comment: on line 140 you have 10 / 0 which is not possible .You must remove it or replace 0 with a greater number

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says Division Error by 0. This error means that you are trying to divide a number with 0, which is not possible. Consider changing it to number other that zero

Comment: I will give it a try and follow up here. This worked on a previous server as is, so i'm not sure why it's giving grief about that 10/0 now.